# New to Ubuntu and need some help.

Tags: internet

Hey guys I'm new to Ubuntu and decided to give it a try in a new rig I just built.
I got it installed on the new machine and then when I plug my Linksys AE1200
USB wireless adapter in to connect to the internet nothing happens. 
It is Ubuntu 14.04 and I have used the lsusb In The Terminal and It shows that the 
Adapter is recognized but I can't get it to connect the internet.

Comment: Pleare rewrite to make clear what you're asking, including in the title. And show some more info, look at/ show logs (/var/log/syslog).

Answer (score 0):

That's because there are no internet drivers for the USB adapter. Try plugging it in to a wired connection then trying to find some installable software for the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the search function in the future, this is an answered question  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100090/how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-my-linksys-ae1200-wireless-n-usb-adapter).

Also [here](http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Adapters/AE1200-linux-Driver/m-p/410963?comm_cc=HSus&comm_lang=en#M30247) is a link to a forum discussion on this very same topic that also has instructions reported to successfully work.

Note this product is not designed to operate with *nix. I hope this helps!