# Cannot get Linksys AE1200 to work with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

Apologies for being a complete and utter newbie - I have much to learn.

Have tried following the steps from many different users and posts - including:

[How do I install the driver for my Linksys AE1200 Wireless-N USB Adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100090/how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-my-linksys-ae1200-wireless-n-usb-adapter)

though I am still running up against trouble and cannot get the driver installed.

My `lsusb` results are as follows:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 13b1:0039 Linksys AE1200 802.11bgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43235]
```

I have also run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install ndisgtk && sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms`

I have downloaded the driver from this location:

http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=159439&t=0&i=1

I have extracted this to my Downloads folder - but now I don't know how to get `bcmwlhigh5.inf` installed.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the dash, look for 'wireless' and select Windows Wireless Drivers. Use it to navigate to the location of the zip file you extracted; as an example, Downloads > xp > bcmwlhigh5.inf. Then click 'Install New Driver.'

If you get stuck, post back and I will edit my answer to assist you further.