# Can't get my Linksys USB wifi adapter to work

Tags: wireless, usb, ndiswrapper

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't get an Internet Connection. The only means I have of connecting to the Internet is my Linksys USB wifi adapter (model AE-1200). The `lsusb` command shows me that it is there but I can't do anything with it.

Some of the other answers I've seen here involve downloading software and/or other programs to make it work. Is there any other way to make it work, considering I can't get my computer online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance this question has been asked before, and a good explanation of your problems exists here: https://askubuntu.com/a/203339/174139

It seems like you will need to employ **[ndiswrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper)** to apply a Broadcom Windows XP Driver to your system. Unfortunately you will need an internet connection to download that driver, unless you have a copy on the CD that came with the AE1200.